# how to launch java GUI test from linux

Tags: java, automated-tests

`-java -classpath<> <classname>` in the ".bat" file to launch java test from cmd windows 
how to do that using perl to launch java test from linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use perl.  For such a simple job, a simple shell script will do:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/java -classpath foo.jar:bar.jar:. classname
```

Make the file executable with `chmod +x filename` and execute it with `./filename`

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach using the `-jar` option is possible. Additionally, you can forward any command line parameters using the special parameter `@`.

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/java -jar foo.jar "${@}"
```